# invoking method via reference variable

Tags: java, methods, instance, system.out

I'm trying to understand how System.out can invoke println(). All the searches  say System.out is an instance of PrintStream class therefore it can invoke a method in that class.

BUT...

When I try to duplicate this with the following a NullPointerException results.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Tasker.calc.add(1, 2);
    }
}

class Tasker{
    static Calc calc;
}

class Calc {
    public void add(int x, int y){
        System.out.println(x+y);
    }
}
```

Isn't Tasker.calc a similar instance of Calc?
How is System.out not a NullPointerException?

To be clear, this is not a question about NullPointerException... this is a question about why System.out doesn't require initialization.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You never intialized `Tasker.calc`, hence you are getting this exception.  You might want to read a good Java tutorial before you get started, Oracle's trails are a good start.

Comment: You have not initialized calc

Comment: You have not initialized the `calc` variable.  Therefore it has the value `null`.  (By contrast, the Java runtime automatically initializes `System.out` to a non-null value.)

Comment: I am thinking what to dup-close this too... What is Nullpointerexception? Thoughts anybody?

Comment: How come I don't have to initialize System.out with 'new'?

Comment: Because the system takes care of that.  It is special.  (And besides, there is no way that you *could* correctly initialize it.  That variable is set to point to the JVM's standard output stream, and there is no way to find out what it should be ...)  Hint: *read the javadocs!*

Comment: [What does your step debugger tell you?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Read up what `static` variables are and how they work.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson - this is nothing to do with static methods.  It is about the (default) initialization of fields ... and the unusual behavior of `System.xxx`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen et al.  This is not really about NPEs either.

Comment: Thank you David! That hit the spot :)

Comment: @StephenC Agree with your Javadoc comment, disagree about closing as a dupe, but since you outrank me I won't touch this question again.

Comment: `System.out` is a `static reference to an outputstream` so it has everything to do with `static` variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why doesn't `System.out` require initialisation?  Well ...

Deep inside the `System` class, there's a method called `initializeSystemClass` which the JVM calls. It sets `System.out` to the right value, so you don't have to.

Note that `System.out` is NOT an instance of `PrintStream` - it's a REFERENCE to an instance of `PrintStream`.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't _initialized `calc`.  You *could* have written

```
static Calc calc = new Calc();
```

and it would have worked (depending on the definition of Calc).

Comment: Why wouldn't I answer this or any question?

Answer (score 0):

As @LouisWasserman points out, the reason that your code gives an NPE is that you haven't initialized the `calc` variable.  As a result, it gets *default initialized* to `null`.  The solution: initialize it!

But the deeper question is why `System.out` doesn't need to be initialized.  That is because the Java runtime initializes it behind the scenes to point to a PrintStream that refers to your application's (external) standard output.

- You don't need to initialize `System.out` because the system does it.  The [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) say so.
- You couldn't initialize it in the nromal way because `System.out` is declared as `final`.  (But there is `System.setOut(...)`)
- Even with `System.setOut(...)` there is no way for an application to find out what `System.out` *should be* set to.  (Consider this `java Test | wc` )